# Fetch data from Firebase, update value in Text widget, and auto-update on changes. Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch data from Firebase and update the value in a Text widget in Flutter. Additionally, I would like the Text widget to be automatically updated whenever the value changes

I am a newbie to flutter and I have no idea about this thing. please assist me with this...

Comment: You can use stream builder for that. Whenever you got new data you can add that data in stream

Answer (score 1):

to create data in firestore!
first create a button on place the method in it.

```dart
    createData() {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('your collection named')
          .doc("your document id or blank it")
          .set({
        "name": "Jackson",
        "age": 15,
      });
    }
```

for fetching data you have to create a widget that returns Text;

```dart
    StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('your collection named')
                .doc("your document id or blank it")
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                DocumentSnapshot userData = snapshot.data!;
                return Text(userData["name"]);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                print(Error); //just for checking
              }
              return const CircularProgressIndicator(); // loading progress indicate
            });
```

for update a data .
first create a button on place the method in it.

```dart
     updateData() {
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('your collection named')
              .doc("your document id or blank it")
              .update({
            "name": "Peterson",
            "age": 20,
          });
        }
```

so you have to use TextField , TextEditingController, to customise your ui perfectly.

Comment: Actually, I was using Firebase **Realtime** Database, not Firestore.

Comment: you can update real time text data or number data in firestore. it's easy in firestore.. Firebase Database used for image , videos etc multimedia files.
what kind of text data you want to use in your firebase database , can you give me some examples !????

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase Remote Configuration
refer the below links
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=flutter

https://medium.com/teamkraken/using-firebase-remote-config-in-flutter-dec10d712c68